# Are visual elements used to reinforce a brand considered visual clutter?

Tags: gui-design

Let's say, a logo of a brand is turquoise and we use that same turquoise, as a strip on the top of a form (example from https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/ux-checklist-series-form-design/) like below: [image]

Is this considered visual clutter?

Comment: In this case, even if it is considered visual clutter, I would say that it has been minimized while still achieving the purpose of brand identification. Sticking a large image of the company logo would probably be more of a visual clutter. Keep in mind that this is somewhat subjective but  it is about achieving the right balance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide user case, so the answer will be DEPENDS.

First, if it has a dominant brand color, it would be advisable to have all the important elements (such as CTA) so that they are of a different color. This is called [accent color](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/what-is-the-value-of-accent-colors-with-regards-to-ux).

However, in small decorative elements (such as the color bar in your sample forms), using the same dominant shade will probably work well.

But if you have elements with positive / negative connotations (such as the icons in your example forms), then it is better to get away from the dominant hue. The negative connotations are obvious so I won't extend.

But you may be tempted to join positive connotations with the colors of the brand. After all, it's a positive connotation, right? While this is true, and you should not use only the color to convey a status message, the color of the elements will generally be scanned faster. If you use the same dominant hues, your status message will probably be scanned as a decorative element and may be ignored (or at least cause some degree of friction), so it is better to use a different hue or shade

So, the real answer to your question (and most of UX's questions) is: just TEST! :)